# SQL - Access outer table from the most inner conditional clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with this SQL query because the most inner WHERE clause can't access to h.ID (error: The multi-part identifier "h.ID" could not be bound). However I can't see other related post have the similar issue to mine.

Is there any other way that I can do?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 as h
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT * 
     FROM ( SELECT r.num * d.num AS value 
            FROM dbo.table2 r
            JOIN dbo.table3 d
            ON d.ID = r.ID
            WHERE r.ID = h.ID
          ) m
     WHERE m.value > 1000
   ) mm
ON mm.ID = h.ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 h LEFT JOIN
     dbo.table2 r
     ON r.ID = h.ID AND r.value > 1000;
```

EDIT:

This should be essentially what you want:

```
SELECT h.*, r.num * d.num AS value 
FROM dbo.table1 h LEFT JOIN
     dbo.table2 r 
     ON r.ID = h.ID LEFT JOIN
     dbo.table3 d
     ON d.ID = r.ID AND r.num * d.num > 1000;
```

Comment: Sorry the `table2 r` doesn't have `value` itself. It is calculated by another column in `table3 d`. I have just edited it to be more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.table1 as h
    LEFT JOIN
       ( SELECT * 
         FROM ( SELECT r.num * d.num AS value ,r.ID AS ID
            FROM dbo.table2 r
            JOIN dbo.table3 d
            ON d.ID = r.ID
        WHERE r.ID = d.ID
      ) m
     WHERE m.value > 1000
   ) mm
ON mm.ID = h.ID;
```